# Dask - How to save memory, for example by partially reading csv?

Tags: pandas, dask

I have two csv files. One main file `file1` and one `file2` with rows that need to be removed in `file1`.
After these rows are deleted, a groupby will be done on `mainnumber` while saving a sum and count.

Unfortunately, my datasets seems too big for my 32GB memory as the process is killed. I only have this server available, no other workers.

Are there any possibilities to optimize my code from a memory-perspective?
Maybe by reading `file2.csv` in parts?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

def custom_cut(partition, bins, labels):
    result = pd.cut(x=partition["mainnumber"], bins=bins, labels=labels)
    return result

colnames=['mainnumber', 'number', 'index', 'amount'] 
dfone = dd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=colnames, header=0, dtype={'mainnumber': 'Int64', 'number': 'Int64', 'index': 'Int64', 'amount': 'Int64'})

colnames=['mainnumber', 'number', 'index'] 
dftwo = dd.read_csv('file2.csv', names=colnames, header=None, dtype={'mainnumber': 'Int64', 'number': 'Int64', 'index': 'Int64'})

dftwo = dftwo[dftwo["index"] < 10000] #Remove some data

dfnew  = dd.merge(dfone, dftwo, how='left', indicator='Exist')
del dfone
del dftwo
dfnew  = dfnew.loc[dfnew ['Exist'] != 'both']
dfnew = dfnew.drop(columns=['Exist'])

dfnew = (dfnew.groupby('mainnumber')['amount'].agg(['sum', 'count']).reset_index())

#Some example bins:
dfnew = dfnew.groupby(dfnew.map_partitions(custom_cut,               
    bins=[0,1000,2000], 
    labels=['first', 'second']))[['sum', 'count']].sum().reset_index()

dfnew = dfnew.compute()

#Write some values to database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save memory, I would use the, `usecols` and `memory_limit` parameters of `dask.read_csv`. Also consider if you need a int64 or you could use uint32, for instance. Another option is to use categorical values except for the "amount" field.

```
dtype = {'mainnumber': 'category', 'number': 'category', 'index': 'category', 'amount': 'int64'}
dfone = dd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=colnames, usecols=colnames, header=0, blocksize="4GB", dtype=dtype)
```

To save even more memory, you may try to do the merging directly:

```
dfnew  = dd.merge(
    dd.read_csv('file1.csv', names=colnames, usecols=colnames, header=0, blocksize="4GB", dtype=dtype),
    dd.read_csv('file2.csv', names=colnames, usecols=colnames, header=0, blocksize="4GB", dtype=dtype),
    how='left', indicator='Exist')
```

Then you can drop the indexes inplace to avoid creating a copy:

```
indexes_to_drop = dfnew.index[dfnew['Exist'] != 'both']
dfnew.drop(index=indexes_to_drop, inplace=True)
dfnew.drop(column='Exist', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! What value do you advice for `memory_limit` as I don't have other tasks running and 32GB available? 
I think the `how='inner'` isn't correct? I try to delete all values from dftwo in dfone and save the result in dfnew.

Comment: @Scripter you are right, you need to do the left join. For the memory_limit I would try the highest possible, try "8GB" or "4GB".

Comment: Thanks. I haven't considered the direct merge because of `dftwo = dftwo[dftwo["index"] < 10000]`, as `dfone` only contains `index` values below 10000. I think this will create rows in `dfnew` if I don't remove them before the merge? What is the meaning of using variable `indexes_to_drop`? Shouldn't this be dfnew or no variable at all?

Comment: `read_csv` has no argument `memory_limit` unfortunately (`TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'memory_limit'`).

Comment: Ok, sorry, the correct parameter is `blocksize`. I will correct the answer. In any case, I would try to use the categories if they fit just as a pandas dataframe before using dask.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. It would be great if you could respond on my other comment before the `read_csv` as well.

Comment: Regarding the filter in dftwo, you are right, you will need to read it and then filter indexes below 10000. The `indexes_to_drop` is a variable needed to drop inplace.